# How to create a vector from percent distribution with 12.5 in R

Tags: r, distribution, percentage

How do I create a vector of size 100 for this distribution?

```
Value   %
0      75
1      12.5
2      12.5
```

I tried:

```
x <- c(rep(0, 75), rep(1, 12.5), rep(2, 12.5))
> x
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[77] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
> length(x)
[1] 99
```

Comment: So you need to create a vector (or a part of it) of non-integer length? How's that possible?

Comment: Can you describe what "half 1 and half 2" should look like? Sidenote, your code could be shortened to `rep(0:2, c(75, 12.5, 12.5))`

Comment: @markus  I was noticing the failure of my bad attempt

Comment: What do you expect to get as output when you do `rep(1, 12.5)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I am misusing rep, thanks, I don't know how to create a vector composed of a distribution of non-integer percents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, what do you expect when you ask for an ½ element to have a value?

One way to solve it is by a throw of a dice.

```
values <- 0:2
pcts <- c(75, 12.5, 12.5)
n <- sum(pcts) ## if you need a different number than 100, 
               ## some modifications in the following is required.
res1 <- rep(values, floor(pcts))
```

But what to do with the last? Ask the machine:

```
set.seed(1512)
res2 <- sample(values, n - length(res1), prob=pcts)

result <- c(res1, res2)
```

If you want to make it reproducible (i.e. the sampling returns same number every time you run the script), you need the `set.seed`.